# ERROR @angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module. from '@angular/material';

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I installed angular materials using `ng add @angular/material`

Then I wrote following codes in app.module.ts file

```
import {MatInputModule,MatCardModule,MatButtonModule} from'@angular/material';
```

Then I encountered the following error.
**ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:14:8 - error TS2306: File 'D:/Develop/Angular/brightway-app/node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module.  14 } from '@angular/material';**

Instead above codes, I used

```
import { MatInputModule  } from "@angular/material/input";

import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';

import { MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
```

It worked successfully.

**What can be the reason for the issue I encountered with first code? Can you please clarify it?**

Answer (score 1):

@angular/material changed its folder structure

At first `index.d.ts` had export statement for all modules now it doesnt

in previous versions you can see several `d.ts` files present at location `..node_modules/@angular/material`(i.e. for serveral modules) which used to import a module from their respective folder( like this `export * from './button/index';`) and we just used to import this file

But now these files have been moved to their respective folders(i.e. inside buttons folder). Therefore, now we need to import from respective folders

Answer (score 0):

You can check the source code of [@angular/material here](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/material) (and see that there is no module at the root directory, which cause your error).

It's only a guess, but based on your error I assume they split the big material module into smaller ones.

Before you have one `MaterialModule` which contains everything. Now this module does not exist anymore, instead you have a lot of specialised module like `MatInputModule`, `MatCardModule`, `MatButtonModule`...

This allow the compiler to do better code splitting and only keep necessary code, which make your bundle lighter :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this when importing the mat modules for your **app.module**

```
import { MatInputModule, MatCardModule , MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
```

and please make sure to add the modules to the import array in **app.module**

```
imports: [
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
```